# Spring Boot - Have hierarchical classes for entities, parent contains the ID

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm creating an API for an existing SQL database. My class system works the following way:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ParentStat {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String UUID;

    // More fields
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "some_data")
public class ChildStat extends ParentStat {
    // Fields
}
```

Having the child stat not extend game stat and just contain it's methods works, but extending the class makes the code not compile (IDE also suggests ChildStat should have an Id).

I tried making the ParentStat abstract and it did not work. Any ideas on what could fix the issue?

EDIT: I changed the imports to javax.persistence and now the following error appears:

````
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gameStatController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sqlService': Error creating bean with name 'SQLService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sqlRepository': Error creating bean with name 'SQLRepository' defined in org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.repositories.SQLRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on PlayerDataApiApplication: Not a managed type: class org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.classes.instances.DRStat
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.PlayerDataApiApplication.main(PlayerDataApiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SQLService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sqlRepository': Error creating bean with name 'SQLRepository' defined in org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.repositories.SQLRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on PlayerDataApiApplication: Not a managed type: class org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.classes.instances.DRStat
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SQLRepository' defined in org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.repositories.SQLRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on PlayerDataApiApplication: Not a managed type: class org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.classes.instances.DRStat
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.randomcraft.PlayerDataAPI.classes.instances.DRStat
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1808) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
    ... 44 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: Parent should be `abstract` and have a `@MappedSuperClass` annotation from JPA else it won't be taken into account. Another thing `@Data` and JPA entities are a bad idea.

Comment: @M.Deinum what dependency is `@MappedSuperClass` part of? I have both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` installed, however it doesn't recognize the annotation. EDIT: I figured out it's part of the `javax.persistence` package, however all my annotations are part of `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: javax.persistence is the correct one for JPA

Comment: I added an edit with a new issue.

Comment: Figured it out, thanks everyone for the help! The issue was inconsistent imports.

Comment: As you already figured out `@MappedSuperclass` is from the JPA packages (`jakarta.persistence`). If you have any decent IDE you could have typed it and code completion would do the rest (or use a search).

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases don't have a straightforward way to map class hierarchies onto database tables. To address this, the JPA specification provides several strategies:

- MappedSuperclass – the parent classes, can't be entities.
- Single Table - The entities from different classes with a common
  ancestor are placed in a single table.
- Joined Table – Each class has its table, and querying a subclass
  entity requires joining the tables.
- Table per Class – All the properties of a class are in its table, so
  no join is required.

Each strategy results in a different database structure.

I assume that you have a separate table for each child. In your case the (first) child is the table *some_data* with a column *uuid* (as primary key) and other columns.

**The solution** with MappedSuperclass annotation:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ParentSuperClass {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String UUID;
    // More fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "some_data")
public class ChildStat extends ParentStat {
    // Fields
}
```

(Getters, setters, constructors not part of the question)